# Components still end up in component tree even when rendered attribute is false

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, rendered-attribute

Mojarra 2.1.

I checked the method `public void execute(FacesContext facesContext) throws FacesException` in the class `com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase`. Now, once the view's restored by the invokation  `viewRoot = viewHandler.restoreView(facesContext, viewId);` we have the compelete tree from the previous request (if it's a postback).

I checked that tree (manually iterate through the `children` properties of the components in a debugger) and found that the composite components, declared as follows:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.id == 1}">
    <utils:dropDownListFilterItem  />
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.id == 2}">
    <utils:dateFilterItem />
 </h:panelGroup>
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.id == 3}">
    <utils:fieldFilterItem />
</h:panelGroup>
```

were all in that tree. It happaned in spite of the fact that `#{bean.id}` was evaluated to 2. I expceted that the only `<utils:dateFilterItem />` instance would be in the tree.

So, my question is how the `rendered` attribute is handled by Mojarra? Is the attribute infuences the only render-responces phase?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rendered attribute is not used during the `RestoreView`-Phase. The first time it is evaluated is in the `ApplyRequestValue`-Phase. This is because during the `RestoreView`-Phase there are no Request Values applied. Thus the `rendered`-attribute which might depend on these values cannot be evaluated.

> were all in that tree. It happaned in spite of the fact that #{bean.id} was evaluated to 2. I expceted that the only  instance would be in the tree.

The component tree **of JSF** is aware of *all* components, no matter if they are rendered or not. This allows you to *rerender* a certain component with all it's inner components (often used with checkboxes etc.) If the inner - not yet rendered components - would be missing inside the component tree, the usage of `render="outerComponent"` would not be able to show the inner components if their `rendered`-attribute now evaluates to true.

To avoid a component beeing added to that tree at all, you have to use a **JSTL**-Tag such as `<c:if >` - if this evaluates to false, the component would not be added to the component tree at all, so JSF would start processing the tree without knowing about a certain component.

You may also want to read this post, where the difference is explained with examples and much more detail: 
[JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)